# how to change cookies life time without from admin login

Tags: magento-1.8, session, cookie

Accidently I have changed the cookies life time = 1 seconds,

Now I am not able to change it to other values, Because When I login my session will destroyed in 1 second.

So Any one know that how can I change cookies lifetime without login from admin panel?.

Or is there any other any other way to set it?

Help Me. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update "web/cookie/cookie_lifetime" in the "core_config_data" table of your database.

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '3600' WHERE `core_config_data`.`config_id` = 35;
```

As long as 35 is the config_id in your database :)  If you can't check, then you could do it by

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '3600' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/cookie/cookie_lifetime';
```